# Read More for dynamic content using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am very new to `jQuery` and also for web design.

Here is the code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxvCe

I got few examples to help me out but they were not exactly what I was looking for.

What I want is.

1. Read more should be hidden if content is less.
2. on click of read more complete content should be visible
3. Text should toggle from read more to read less.
4. On click of read less content should have its previous height.

HTML

```
<div class="readMoreCnt">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>

    <a href="" class="readMore">Read More</a>
    </div>
  <div class="span3">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>

    <a href="" class="readMore">Read More</a>
    </div>
  <div class="span3">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    <a href="" class="readMore">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>

    <a href="" class="readMore">Read More</a>
    </div>
  <div class="span3">

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor </p>

    <a href="" class="readMore">Read More</a>
    </div>
  <div class="span3">

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>

    <a href="" class="readMore">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.readMoreCnt p {
  height: 145px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

I am not able to know how can I show a content which is already present.

I can do `slideUp` and `slideDown` but it can not work as its already shown.

Comment: Where is your Javascript?

Comment: I am not able to build the logic what needs to be done for showing the element which is already shown.

Comment: You can try to animate by max-height.

Comment: Or Your can try to animate the opacity. Than it's like fadeIn/Out.

Comment: yup max-height can be a good Idea, I will give it a try. Thanks @Tushar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [DEMO](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/xFgBD).

You need to add few more div's and get the height for child and apply it to parent.

**JQUERY**

```
/*To hide read more if content is less*/
$('.inCnt').each(function(){
  if ($(this).height() <= 145) {
    $(this).parent('.inner').next('.readMore').hide()
  }
})

$('.readMore').click(function(){
  var cntHeight = $(this).parent('.span3').find('.inCnt').height();
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $('.readMore').removeClass('active').html('Read More'); 
    $('.inner').animate({
      maxHeight: '145px'
    });
  } else {
    $('.readMore').removeClass('active').html('Read More'); 
    $('.inner').animate({
      maxHeight: '145px'
    });
  $(this).prev('.inner').animate({
      maxHeight: cntHeight
    }, function(){
    $(this).next('.readMore').addClass('active').html('Read Less');
  });
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Awesome!!! Thanks tushar. This needs few changes I can manage that. Thanks a Lots.

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you can use [jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), like below..

```
$(".readMore").click(function(){
    if($(this).siblings("p").css("height") == "50px"){
         $(this).siblings("p").animate({
                                        height: "+=50"
                                      }, 200);
    }    
    else{
        $(this).siblings("p").animate({
                                        height: "-=50"
                                      }, 200);
    }
});
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N8VQP/)..

**NOTE:** I change your default height from 145px to 50px..

Comment: Thanks for answer, however this wont work for dynamic content.